# Wifi doesn't have a valid ip configuration? (URGENT!!!)

Tags: wireless-networking

I've been trying to fix this for two hours. I am an artist as a living and I have commissions to fill so I have to get this done soon. My home wifi is 'limited' and is not working. I don't want to uninstall anything and I need it fixed by tonight otherwise I'm screwed. Please help.

Comment: You asked your question and the urgency to you won't affect the speed or quality of the answers you receive.  Posting a second time will just slow things down because this post does not contain enough information for anyone to be able to help.  It will waste everyone's time clarifying two of the same question.  People who have something to contribute are not withholding answers because the question doesn't say "URGENT" or hasn't been posted often enough.  Please delete this post and focus on your original question.

Comment: 'Limited' networking in Windows lingo means no Internet connection. Since you haven't been able to fix this problem in a timely manner, you should contact your ISP's technical support, especially if you didn't change anything on the router before this problem occurred. They might've made some configuration changes on their end.

Answer (score 0):

The most **Limited Connection problem** is due the interference to your wifi network from other wireless router  and **starvation of IP addresses** in your DHCP server which is running in your router

**To fix this problem**

1. Increase the pool of Ip address in your DHCP server which is running
2. Change the wireless channel in your router (1, 6, 11 are non overlapping channels) are the most common used,
3. Increase frequency Band from 20 MHZ to 40 MHZ

**Temporary Solution**

Restart your router,
as this will disconnect all clients from the router, and allow the other wireless device to connect to the wifi router.

let say, if your neighbor router used the channel no 6 (most router has default setup of 6) and your router has also of 6 then there will be the chance of interference from both of the wifi device to each other, as they operate on same frequency 2.4 or 5 GHZ(regardless of modulation method), so to fix this change the wireless chanel

Comment: Please don't answer this question, post your answer on the original question identified by DavidPostill.

Comment: This is pretty much a complete guess.